# How to test for Chromium(III) Oxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I got some chromium(III) oxide ($\ce{Cr2O3}$) sold as pigment, called "Chrome Green". I've been having a hard time trying to react it with $\ce{HCl}$ to make $\ce{CrCl3}$. I thought it was just hard to break the $\ce{Cr-O}$ bond.

Now I'm just afraid that the pigment that I bought was actually cut with something else, like a silicate-type of pigment. How do I test for chrome(III) oxide, if I can't get it to become a salt in the first place?

Comment: I was thinking of roasting it in *excess* amounts with either $NaCO_{3}$ or $NaOH$ to get sodium chromate or chromite (the chromite I can just further oxidize). Dissolve it all in water and then dry it. If I see any white specs I can assume them to be sodium silicate. But this only tests for silicates mixed in. I want to know if the store I bought it from mixed it with enough actual $Cr_{2}O_{3}$. Perhaps, a test specific to Chromium ions would be better

Answer (score 2):

The test for $\ce{Cr(III)}$ can be performed in the solid state using an [*oxidative melt*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufschluss_(Chemie)#Oxidationsschmelze). You will need

- chromium(III) oxide (obviously)
- sodium carbonate
- potassium nitrate
- a [*Bunsen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunsen_burner) or [*Teclu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teclu_burner) burner
- a [magnesia trough](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesiarinne) or a crucible
- suitable [pliers](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauchzange) to hold the trough

Mix the green pigment with up to the threefold amount of sodium carbonate and potassium nitrate, place the mixture on the magnesia trough and melt it.

A yellow melt indicates the formation of sodium chromate according to

$\ce{Cr2O3 + 3KNO3 + 2Na2CO3 -> 2Na2CrO4 + 3KNO2 + 2CO2 ^}$

Answer (score 0):

Chromium(III) oxide contains $\ce{Cr^3+}$ which can be detected through salt analysis. Only specific test for $\ce{Cr^3+}$ is mentioned.

1. Source 1*

> $$\ce{Cr^3+(aq) + 3OH^{–}(aq) -> Cr(OH)3(s)}$$
>
> Chromium(III) hydroxide is formed when $\ce{Cr^3+}$ is treated with
>   ammonia or sodium hydroxide, which is soluble in excess alkaline
>   solution (amphoteric, dissolves in acids too) but not soluble in
>   excess ammonia . With sodium hydroxide, a dark green soluble
>   hexahydroxo–complex ion is formed.
>
> $$\ce{Cr(OH)3(s) + 3NaOH(aq) -> [Cr(OH)6]^{3–}(aq)}$$

2. Source 2**

> Chromium can be taken through a series of colored tests which leaves
>   no doubt as to its identity. Chromium(III) forms a steel green
>   hydroxide which dissolves in excess strong base to give a deeply green
>   colored solution of the hydroxy complex. Treating this complex with 3%
>   hydrogen peroxide gives the yellow solution of the chromate ion, which
>   upon acidification with dilute nitric acid gives the orange color of
>   dichromate. Treatment of the cold solution of dichromate with 3%
>   hydrogen peroxide gives the intense blue color of a peroxide of
>   chromium. (The actual composition of this peroxide is not known, but
>   it is believed to have the empirical formula $\ce{CrO5}$). This
>   peroxide readily decomposes to the pale violet color of the original
>   hydrated chromium(III) ion. In low concentrations of dichromate the
>   blue color is fleeting, and attention must be focused on the test tube
>   during the addition of the hydrogen peroxide to avoid missing the
>   color change.
>
> $$\ce{Cr(OH)^{4-} (green) + H2O2 + OH^{-}→ CrO4^{2-}(yellow)}$$
>   $$\ce{CrO4^{2-} + H+→ Cr2O7^{2-} (orange)}$$ $$\ce{Cr2O7^{2-} + H2O2 +
> HNO3→ CrO5 (blue)→ [Cr(H2O)6]^3+ (violet)}$$
>
> The following color changes are all indicative of $\ce{Cr^3+}$. Add an
>   excess of 6 M $\ce{NaOH}$ to about one mL of test solution. To this
>   green solution add 10 drops of 3% $\ce{H2O2}$. Heat the test tube in
>   the water bath until the excess $\ce{H2O2}$ is destroyed as indicated
>   by the cessation of bubbles. Acidify the yellow solution with 3 M
>   $\ce{HNO3}$. Cool the resulting orange solution in an ice bath. To the
>   cooled solution add a drop or two of 3% $\ce{H2O2}$ and observe the
>   immediate fleeting blue color.

**Reference**

*http://www.docbrown.info/page13/ChemicalTests/ChemicalTestsc.htm

**http://www.wiredchemist.com/chemistry/instructional/laboratory-tutorials/qualitative-analysis

Comment: Is the acidification with $HNO_{3}$ specific to the test? Is it because you need a strong oxidizing acid? Or would common $HCl$ suffice?